# SQL - Multiple records into one line with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that look like this

Account Table

```
| Account Number | Account Name   |
| -------------- | -------------- |
| 12345          | Bob Jones      |
| 12346          | Jenny Smith    |
| 12347          | Mary Frederick |
```

Email Table

```
| Account Number         | Email Type    |Email                  | IsPrimary       |
| ---------------------- | --------------|-----------------------|-----------------|
| 12345                  | WORK          | BOBSMITH@STACK.COM    | 0               |  
| 12345                  | HOME          | BOBSMITH@GMAIL.COM    | 0               |
| 12345                  | WORK          | BOBSMITH@APPLE.COM    | 1               |
| 12345                  | HOME          | BOBSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM  | 0               |
| 12346                  | HOME          | JMSMITH@GMAIL.COM     | 1               |
| 12346                  | WORK          | JMSMITH@DISNEY.COM    | 0               |
| 12346                  | HOME          | JMSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM   | 0               |
| 12347                  | HOME          | MFRED@HOTMAIL.COM     | 0               |
```

I need to end up with results like this:

```
| Account Number           | Account Name      | Home Email         | Work Email         | Alternate Email      |
| ------------------------ | ----------------- |--------------------|--------------------|----------------------|
| 12345                    | Bob Jones         | BOBSMITH@GMAIL.COM | BOBSMITH@APPLE.COM | BOBSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM |
| 12346                    | Jenny Smith       | JMSMITH@GMAIL.COM  | JMSMITH@DISNEY.COM | JMSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM  |
| 12347                    | Mary Frederick    | MFRED@HOTMAIL.COM  |                    |                      |
```

I have all possible combinations of emails such as multiple work and no home, no primaries at all, multiple primaries... etc.

I need the logic to be:

- Home Email: When type is Home. If there is a primary, choose the first one. If there is no primary, choose the first non-primary home email. Otherwise make it blank
- Work Email: Same as above but for work
- Alternate Email: Any third email on the list. If there are more than 3, choose home over work.

I have tried a ton of things and nothing has worked well. Here is my top attempt -two things don't work about it. The 'top 1' returns a lot of nulls and the code for alternates isn't always mutually exclusive to the home and work email, especially for people that have no primary checked:

```
select distinct
A01.AccountNumber, 
A01.FirstName,
A01.LastName,
(
    select top 1 
    case
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME' and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1)
        then A07.EmailAddress
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'HOME')
        then A07.EmailAddress
    end 
    from A07_AccountEmails AS A07 
    where A07.AccountNumber = A01.AccountNumber

) as HomeEmail
,(
    select top 1 
    case
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'WORK'  and A07.EmailType is not null)--and A07.UseAsPrimary = 1)
        then A07.EmailAddress
       when (A07.Active = 1 and A07.EmailType = 'WORK')
        then A07.EmailAddress
    end 
    from A07_AccountEmails AS A07 
    where A07.AccountNumber = A01.AccountNumber 

) as WorkEmail
,(
    select top 1 (A07.EmailAddress)
    from A07_AccountEmails A07
    where A07.AccountNumber = A01.AccountNumber
    and A07.Active = 1 and A07.UseAsPrimary = 0
) as AlternateEmailMulti
from A01_AccountMaster A01
left outer join A07_AccountEmails A07 on A07.AccountNumber = A01.AccountNumber
where
A01.[Status] = 'A'
```

Comment: If we made a list with 4 columns : Account Number, Name, work e-mails, home e-mails with the e-mail column containing all the e-mails in a comme seperated list, primary first would that do the job?

Comment: @Kendle Not sure I quite get it, but it needs to be one line per account.

Comment: @DaleK I have tried a nested select for each of the email types. It doesn't work for the alternate because I can't figure out how to make it mutually exclusive from the home and work. I have tried a double join and it sort of works if I only use home but makes it hard when I bring in work.

Comment: @DaleK See updated post

Comment: Note: You really want to ensure that your query and data are consistent in terms of column names etc. Else it leads to all sorts of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a simple sub-query per email address should do the trick? I have added them in an `OUTER APPLY` to allow the values to be used twice, once in the select, and once to be excluded from the alternate email column.

```
declare @Account table (Number int, [Name] varchar(64));
declare @Email table (AccountNumber int, [Type] varchar(4), Email varchar(256), IsPrimary bit);

insert into @Account (Number, [Name])
values
(12345, 'Bob Jones'),
(12346, 'Jenny Smith'),
(12347, 'Mary Frederick');

insert into @Email (AccountNumber, [Type], Email, IsPrimary)
values
(12345, 'WORK', 'BOBSMITH@STACK.COM', 0),
(12345, 'HOME', 'BOBSMITH@GMAIL.COM', 0),
(12345, 'WORK', 'BOBSMITH@APPLE.COM', 1),
(12345, 'HOME', 'BOBSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM', 0),
(12346, 'HOME', 'JMSMITH@GMAIL.COM', 1),
(12346, 'WORK', 'JMSMITH@DISNEY.COM', 0),
(12346, 'HOME', 'JMSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM', 0),
(12347, 'HOME', 'MFRED@HOTMAIL.COM', 0);

select A.Number, A.[Name]
  , E.Home [Home Email]
  , E.Work [Work Email]
  , (
    select top 1 Email
    from @Email
    where AccountNumber = A.Number
    and Email not in (E.Home, E.Work)
    order by case when [Type] = 'HOME' then 1 else 0 end desc
  )
from @Account A
outer apply (
  select 
    (select top 1 Email from @Email where AccountNumber = A.Number and [Type] = 'HOME' order by IsPrimary desc),
    (select top 1 Email from @Email where AccountNumber = A.Number and [Type] = 'WORK' order by IsPrimary desc)
) E (Home, Work);
```

Returns your desired results:

| Account Number | Account Name | Home Email | Work Email | Alternate Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Bob Jones | BOBSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM | BOBSMITH@APPLE.COM | BOBSMITH@GMAIL.COM |
| 12346 | Jenny Smith | JMSMITH@GMAIL.COM | JMSMITH@DISNEY.COM | JMSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM |
| 12347 | Mary Frederick | MFRED@HOTMAIL.COM | NULL | NULL |

Note: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (as I have here) it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Thanks, that is super helpful. How to I insert my existing data (A01_AccountMaster)?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! insert into @Account (Number, [Name])
Select A01.AccountNumber, A01.LastName from A01_AccountMaster A01

Comment: At first pass it looks great, will do more testing next week and mark the answer! Thank you thank you!

Comment: You don't need to insert your existing data into the table variables, you **replace** the references to table variables with your own tables. i.e. you edit the query to use your real tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach which list all e-mails, primaries first.
We use group_,concat to show all matching entries, order by primary prim inversed by desc and finally a newline separator \n to make a vertical list.
NB : It doesn't print correctly in the terminal because of the newlines.

```
USE test;
CREATE TABLE user (
        acc INT,
        nam CHAR(10)
        );
INSERT INTO user VALUES ( 1, 'Andrew');
INSERT INTO user VALUES ( 2, 'Bernard');
INSERT INTO user VALUES ( 3, 'Charles');
CREATE TABLE telMail (
        acc INT,
        email CHAR(25),
        type CHAR(5),
        prim INT
        );
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'a@w0','Work',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'a@w1','Work',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'ap@w2','Work',1);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'a@w3','Work',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'a@h1','Home',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(1,'a@h2','Home',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(2,'b@h1','Home',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(2,'b@w1','Work',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(2,'b@w2','Work',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(3,'c@h1','Home',0);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(3,'cp@h1','Home',1);
INSERT INTO telMail VALUES(3,'c@w1','Work',0);

SELECT
        u.acc 'Account',
        u.nam 'Name',
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.email ORDER BY w.prim DESC SEPARATOR '\n' ) work_mail,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.email ORDER BY h.prim DESC SEPARATOR '\n' ) home_mail

FROM
        (SELECT acc,email,prim FROM telMail WHERE type ='Home') h
JOIN
        user u on u.acc=h.acc
JOIN
        (SELECT acc,email,prim FROM telMail WHERE type ='Work') w ON u.acc = w.acc
GROUP BY u.acc, u.nam
ORDER BY u.acc;
DROP TABLE user;
DROP TABLE telMail;
```